# How to delete child model data in case of on_delete=models.PROTECT?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Let assume i have two models `Meeting` and `Call_Type` and there is ForeignKey relation between them like bellow.

```
class Meeting(SoftDeleteModel):
    name = models.call_type(CallType, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
```

**And:-**

```
class CallType(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
```

Now i have deleted data from meeting table using `Meeting.objects.all().delete()` by mistake, and when trying delete CallType model data i get following error:-

```
ProtectedError: ("Cannot delete some instances of model 'CallType' because they are referenced through protected foreign keys: 'Meeting.call_type'.", {<Meeting: Meeting object (1)>, <Meeting: Meeting object (2)>, <Meeting: Meeting object (3)>, <Meeting: Meeting object (4)>, <Meeting: Meeting object (5)>, <Meeting: Meeting object (6)>, <Meeting: Meeting object (7)>, <Meeting: Meeting object (8)>, <Meeting: Meeting object (9)>, <Meeting: Meeting object (10)>, <Meeting: Meeting object (11)>, <Meeting: Meeting object (12)>})
```

Is there is any way to delete CallType model data.

Thanks in advance.
Hope in here from you soon.

Comment: If this is just one off scenario, I would change the `models.PROTECT` to `models.CASCADE`. Make migrations and migrate. Then remove the items you want. then change the field back to `models.PROTECT` and make migrations and migrate back again.

Comment: Generally I am using the django 3.2.5 and python 3.8 version this should automatically delete the CallType without any error. As you have used SoftDeleteModel not sure about the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Since the foreign key reference is protected, you need to first delete the objects that references that object:

```py
calltype_to_delete = CallType.objects.get(pk=<some_calltype_pk>)

Meeting.objects.filter(name=calltype_to_delete).delete()
```

or if you want to keep the meeting data, you can set their foreign keys to `None` since you've allowed this by using `null=True`:

```py
calltype_to_delete = CallType.objects.get(pk=<some_calltype_pk>)

Meeting.objects.filter(name=calltype_to_delete).update(name=None)
```

Only then can you delete the the `CallType` object:

```
calltype_to_delete.delete()
```